# How to get Target name from inside its' dependency Target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let us say that there is a Makefile with Targets such as:

```
.PHONY: app
target-a: my-dependency
    ...
target-b: my-dependency
    ...
my-dependency:
    # Print the name of the target which depends on this during run-time
```

For example, when this command is made, I would like **my-dependency** to print **target-a**:

```
make target-a
```

For example, when this command is made, I would like **my-dependency** to print **target-b**:

```
make target-b
```

Comment: `@echo $(MAKECMDGOALS)` https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html

Comment: `MAKECMDGOALS` will work, only if the target you want information about is one specified on the make command line.  That's how the example you've given here works but it may be that your real situation is different (that you want to know the parent target where that target _wasn't_ provided on the command line).  If so, `MAKECMDGOALS` won't help.

Comment: There is a way to do this, but as @RonnyBrendel points out, it's an awkward and unnatural thing to do. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't do that.

What you are saying is that `my-dependency` depends on `target-a` or `target-b`.

Depending on what exactly your real code looks like, you should consider having one instance of my-dependency, i.e. `my-dependency-target-a` and `my-dependency-target-b`, modify them according to your wishes and use the appropriate one for each target.

P.S.: If you just want to print the target name you could print the target name in `target-a` and `target-b` and then read in reverse. I.e. the `my-dependency` is from the target next on the console.